# How do I fetch the list of MS Teams users in an organization?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

How do I fetch the list of MS Teams users in an organization? And store and then broadcast a notification to them.
I see this snippet but it fetches the list of members in a conversation only

```
bot.dialog('FetchMemberList', function (session) {
var conversationId = session.message.address.conversation.id;
connector.fetchMembers(session.message.address.serviceUrl, conversationId, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        session.endDialog('There is some error');
    }
    else {
        session.endDialog('%s', JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```

});

Comment: There is nothing built into bot framework itself that can accomplish this natively.  You will have to look at using something like the MS Teams API, or Graph API for this data.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no option to fetch user's unique Id without installing the bot. You need the user’s unique ID and tenant ID to [send a proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#starting-personal-conversations).

Bot can only send proactive message to users who has installed your bot. When user installs your app, you could save user details which can be used later to send messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the list of the users using the Teams roster REST API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context#fetching-the-team-roster

> Your bot can query for the list of team members and their basic profiles, which includes Teams user IDs and Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) information such as name and objectId. You can use this information to correlate user identities; for example, to check whether a user logged into a tab through Azure AD credentials is a member of the team.
>
> You can directly issue a GET request on /conversations/{teamId}/members/, using the value of serviceUrl as the endpoint.
>
> Currently, the only source for teamId is a message from the team context—either a message from a user or the message that your bot receives when it is added to a team (see Bot or user added to a team).

**Response would follow the format:**

```
[{
    "id": "29:1GcS4EyB_oSI8A88XmWBN7NJFyMqe3QGnJdgLfFGkJnVelzRGos0bPbpsfJjcbAD22bmKc4GMbrY2g4JDrrA8vM06X1-cHHle4zOE6U4ttcc",
    "objectId": "9d3e08f9-a7ae-43aa-a4d3-de3f319a8a9c",
    "givenName": "Larry",
    "surname": "Brown",
    "email": "Larry.Brown@fabrikam.com",
    "userPrincipalName": "labrown@fabrikam.com"
},
...
]
```